# If statements and regex in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

is there a way to regex a part of the hostname in htaccess?

Example: if `%{HTTP_HOST}` Matches any of `'/\w{2,}\.(?:site|local)/i'` DO Something

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \w{2,}\.(?:site|local) [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(styles\.php|templates|application/views/elements\.php|hello\.txt)
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What I am trying to achieve is only include the code below if the condition is true.
RewriteCond $1 !^(styles\.php|templates|application/views/elements\.php|hello\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] Sorry I don't work alot with htaccess and its really confusing

Comment: But how is your rule related to `if %{HTTP_HOST}` part of your question?

Comment: 'if(%{HTTP_HOST} MATCHES '/\w{2,}\.(?:site|local)/i'){ RewriteCond $1 !^(styles\.php|templates|application/views/elements\.php|hello\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] }'

Comment: Sadly that didn't work but no worries. Can just be commented out when deploying live. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variant on Anubhava's suggestion:  yes you can do if-type ladder logic using the skip flag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\w{2,}\.(site|local)
RewriteRule ^            -                       [skip:4]

# the next four rules will be skipped
```

Hope this helps.

It's a matter of personal style, but I've taken out the non-capture condition: it's just a little complication for no benefit.  I would also prefer a tighter regexp, for example `!^\w{2,}\.(mysite\.com|local)$` so that you don't get unintended matches  :-)